# Struggling trying to output a tree relationship when given 2 lists (one list for children, other for parents)

Tags: r, graph, tree, traversal, bioinformatics

Been scratching my head for a few days with this one but to no avail. I sort of stumbled across this problem while volunteering with a professor: I have the following data which links organisms with their parents (table could be n entries long):

Organism ID - (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

Parental organism ID - (N/A,1, N/A,2,2,4,3)

(so organism 1 has parent "N/A" (no parent), organsim 2 has parent 1, 3 has parent "N/A", 4 has parent 2, 5 has parent 4, 7 has parent 3)

So pairing up the data (parent[i], child[i]), the relations are:

1->2

2->4

2->5

4->6

3->7

And given this data, I would like to produce some sort of tree visual like: http://imgur.com/gyWC1R0 . Or perhaps putting it into newick format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format)

I've been fiddling around in R (no particular reason, I've just been using R alot lately) with the input of one list for parent id, and another for organism id, but all my attempts have been futile so far.

If anyone has encountered a problem similar to this, or can figure out the general logic to solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like with this little data you could have simply drawn this in 5-10 minutes using some other piece of software (Omnigraffle comes to mind, Photoshop and its analogues, or maybe I mean Illustrator, I don't know those Adobe apps well. Maybe even a basic PDF viewer/editor...?)

Comment: O sorry I should have clarified, this was only one example of 2 lists, I would like to make a general function that inputs 2 lists of this form and produces a tree output

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make a dendrogram manually, as seen in this problem:

[How do I manually create a dendrogram (or "hclust") object ? (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310913/how-do-i-manually-create-a-dendrogram-or-hclust-object-in-r)

However, I'd recommend looking into the kinship2 package for R.

http://alexchubaty.com/index.php/2011/11/constructing-pedigrees-in-r/ shows you how to do make family trees (which sounds like what you're trying to do).

Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with the package, and I'm not sure how to have only one parent.

Comment: So close! It seems like kinship2 requires 2 parents and there isn't anyway around that, but this is still a very cool package.

Comment: Otherwise this would be perfect